When any key pressed, type next character from clipboard, while suppressing keyboard inputs
I'm trying to create a program, that when the selected key bind is activated, will suppress your keyboard inputs, but will use a module to type the next character from your clipboard. The result should allow this:

Set a key bind of any choice, then start the app
Type freely and do whatever
Activate the key bind, and your key presses will not match the output, ex; if you press “j”, it will actually press “T” because “T” is the first item in your clipboard; “The cat”, then when you press any key such as “7”, it will type “h”, because it's the next character in your clipboard.
Be able to cancel the suppressing and simulation of typing at any time by pressing “ESC”, or the program will shut down automatically when your clipboard has finished typing.

Here is my code:
import tkinter as tk
from pynput import keyboard
import threading
import pyperclip  # For accessing the clipboard
import pyautogui

# Global variables
block_keys = False
selected_key = None
keyboard_listener = None
clipboard_content = pyperclip.paste()  # Get the clipboard content
listClipboard = [char for char in clipboard_content]
print(listClipboard)

# Function to listen for the keybind and start blocking
def listen_for_keybind():
    def on_press_keybind(key):
        global block_keys
        if key == selected_key:
            print(f"Keybind {selected_key} activated")
            global char_index
            char_index = 0  # Reset character index
            block_keys = True  # Start blocking keys
            start_blocking_listener()  # Start blocking key presses when keybind is activated
            return False  # Stop the keybind listener once the keybind is pressed

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press_keybind) as keybind_listener:
        keybind_listener.join()


controller = keyboard.Controller()
# Function to start the listener for blocking all key presses 
def start_blocking_listener():
    global keyboard_listener, listener

    # Function to handle key presses 
    # 
    def on_press(key):
        global listClipboard, keyboard_listener, listener
        print(f"Key pressed, not registered: {key}")
        
        if str(key) == "Key.esc":
            stop_blocking()
            return


        if listClipboard:
            keyboard_listener.stop()
            keyboard_listener = None
            pyautogui.typewrite(listClipboard[0])
            print(f"Typed: {listClipboard[0]}")
            listClipboard.pop(0)
            keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, suppress=True)
            keyboard_listener.start()



        

    # Disable keyboard events and print a message on key press
    keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, suppress=True)
    keyboard_listener.start()

def stop_blocking():
    global keyboard_listener
    global block_keys
    block_keys = False
    if keyboard_listener is not None:
        keyboard_listener.stop()
    print("Blocking disabled, typing enabled")

# Function to set the keybind
def set_keybind():
    add_button.config(text="Press any key...", state="disabled")

    
    def on_key_press(key):
        global selected_key
        selected_key = key
        add_button.config(text=f"Keybind set to: {key}", state="normal")
        listener.stop()

    global listener
    listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_key_press)
    listener.start()

# Function to activate the keybind listener
def activate_keybind():
    if selected_key:
        root.withdraw()  # Minimize the window
        # Start a separate thread to listen for the keybind activation
        thread = threading.Thread(target=listen_for_keybind)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
    else:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please set a keybind first.")

# Function to quit the application
def quit_app():
    stop_blocking()
    root.quit()

# Set up the GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Keybind Blocking App")

label = tk.Label(root, text="Click the button below to set the keybind:")
label.pack(pady=10)

add_button = tk.Button(root, text="Add Keybind", command=set_keybind)
add_button.pack(pady=5)

set_button = tk.Button(root, text="Start Blocking", command=activate_keybind)
set_button.pack(pady=5)

quit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=quit_app)
quit_button.pack(pady=5)

root.mainloop()


I tried cancelling the suppressing before controller.type(), but then re-enable it afterward, that did solve the problem where it would register the controller.type() as the next keyboard input, but it still won't type the next character from clipboard.
Ps. There are some small bugs like starting the app without setting the key bind, and maybe you should just start out by putting “0” as the key that will activate the app, because that's all I've tested for.
Help would be appreciated.

All you need to do is have your bound function return the string "break" to prevent the default behavior. You can then insert anything you want.
In the following example, copy something to the clipboard then run the code and press the comma a few times after clicking in the text widget.
import tkinter as tk

clipboard = None
def replace_keystroke(event):
    global clipboard
    if clipboard is None:
        clipboard = root.clipboard_get()
    event.widget.insert("insert", clipboard[0])
    clipboard = clipboard[1:]
    return "break"

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, wrap="word")
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
text.bind("<comma>", replace_keystroke)

tk.mainloop()


This works for the tkinter box, but for example, what if I want it to work in a google doc? Or a different app of any type?

@JudahStarkenburg:  you can't use tkinter to intercept keystrokes in other programs. Tkinter can only manage events within a tkinter app.

That's why I'm not using tkinter to intercept keystrokes, I'm just using tkinter as an interface to customize the app. I'm using pynput to suppress the keybind, and pyautogui to simulate typing.
